# Prolog, diagonal distance

Tags: recursion, prolog, distance

I have grid based map, and I'm trying to develop a predicate that gives me the diagonal distance between 2 points, this is what I have,

```
dist_diagonal((X,Y),(X,W),Passos,D):-
    dist_ortogonal((X,Y),(X,W),D1),
    D is D1 + Passos.

dist_diagonal((X,Y),(Z,Y),Passos,D):-
    dist_ortogonal((X,Y),(Z,Y),D1),
    D is D1 + Passos.

dist_diagonal((X,Y),(Z,W),Passos,_):-
    X>Z,
    Y<W,
    Passos1 is Passos+1,
    X1 is X-1,
    Y1 is Y+1,
    dist_diagonal((X1,Y1),(Z,W),Passos1,_).

dist_diagonal((X,Y),(Z,W),Passos,_):-
    X<Z,
    Y<W,
    Passos1 is Passos+1,
    X1 is X+1,
    Y1 is Y+1,
    dist_diagonal((X1,Y1),(Z,W),Passos1,_).
```

but when I try to test it :

```
dist_diagonal((5,4),(3,8),0,D).
```

I get `true` instead of a value for D

What's wrong with my predicate?

PS: I should add that I'm going to use this only with points that verrify `Y<Z`.
PS2: Notice that I'm calculating the distance using 8 kinds of movements, not the euclidean distance.[Diagonal distance](https://www.google.pt/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi6oNqzuqbQAhVBmBoKHbUtAboQjRwIBw&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftheory.stanford.edu%2F~amitp%2FGameProgramming%2FHeuristics.html&psig=AFQjCNEJ-tdssfSFsCjxZE4AhiFABwOObw&ust=1479151369705820)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write : `dist_diagonal((X,Y),(Z,W),Passos,D):-` instead of `dist_diagonal((X,Y),(Z,W),Passos,_):-`

Your predicate is returning true since D could be anything (since you use anonymous variables '_').

So  you need to write:

```
dist_diagonal((X,Y),(Z,W),Passos,D):-
    X>Z,
    Y<W,
    Passos1 is Passos+1,
    X1 is X-1,
    Y1 is Y+1,
    dist_diagonal((X1,Y1),(Z,W),Passos1,D).

dist_diagonal((X,Y),(Z,W),Passos,D):-
    X<Z,
    Y<W,
    Passos1 is Passos+1,
    X1 is X+1,
    Y1 is Y+1,
    dist_diagonal((X1,Y1),(Z,W),Passos1,D).
```

I wasn't able to test since I have no definition of `dist_ortogonal/3` predicate but I wrote a simple version of it and it worked so it should be working fine.

Comment: Glad that helped!!